# How to traverse a 2D List in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following list:

```
grid = [[2, 6, 8, 6, 9], [2, 5, 5, 5, 0], [1, 3, 8, 8, 7], [3, 2, 0, 6, 9], [2, 1, 4,5,8], [5, 6, 7, 4, 7]]
```

I used the fowling loop for traversing each element ->

```
for i in xrange(len(grid[i])):
    for j in xrange(len(grid[j])):
        print grid[i][j]
    print "\n"
```

But it doesn't show the last row i.e `[5,6,7,4,7]`

So, which is the proper way to travers a 2D List in python?

Comment: `for i in xrange(len(grid[i]))` - There should be no such thing as `grid[i]` when execution enters this loop, because there should not yet be a value for `i`. Perhaps you have mistakenly used a variable for two different purposes in the same function, or perhaps you initialized `i` before the loop (which you shouldn't need to do). If you wanted to do this with range-len iteration (which you shouldn't), the correct lines would be `for i in xrange(len(grid)):` and `for j in xrange(len(grid[i])):`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The proper way to traverse a 2-D list is

```
for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        print item,
    print
```

The `for` loop in Python, will pick each items on every iteration. So, from `grid` 2-D list, on every iteration, 1-D lists are picked. And in the inner loop, individual elements in the 1-D lists are picked.

If you are using Python 3.x, please use the `print` as a function, not as a statement, like this

```
for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        print(item, end = " ")
    print()
```

**Output**

```
2 6 8 6 9
2 5 5 5 0
1 3 8 8 7
3 2 0 6 9
2 1 4 5 8
5 6 7 4 7
```

But, in case, if you want to change the element at a particular index, then you can do

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(grid):
    for col_index, item in enumerate(row):
        gird[row_index][col_index] = 1     # Whatever needs to be assigned.
```

Comment: is there any 2d list operation in python like we did in C

Comment: @DBB You can think of 2-D lists as list of lists. A list object containing other list objects.

Comment: For Python3 users who could pass there: don't forget to change the `print,` Py2 syntax by `print(item, end='')` ;)

Comment: @MaximeLorant Sure, included that as well in the answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi , but now I want perform some basic list operation , is that possible to print like grid [i][j] format because I need to do operate on list column?

Comment: @DBB Do you want to change the element at that position?

Comment: @DBB Please check the answer now, I have included a way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Try following instead. You can do necessary operation instead of "print grid[i][j]"

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[i])):
        print grid[i][j]
    print '---'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
for i in grid:
    for j in i:
        print("{}".format(j))
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following...

```
for i in grid:
    for j in i:
        print j
    print '----'
```

Comment: Hi , but now I want perform some basic list operation , is that possible to print like grid [i][j] format because I need to do operate on list column?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use while loop for traversing the 2D list

```
grid = [[2, 6, 8, 6, 9], [2, 5, 5, 5, 0], [1, 3, 8, 8, 7], [3, 2, 0, 6, 9], [2, 1, 4,5,8], [5, 6, 7, 4, 7]]
i = 0
while i < len(grid):
    j = 0
    while j < len(grid[0]):
        print (grid[i][j], end=' ')
        j += 1
    print() #new line
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns are same in all the inner lists this should like==

```
li = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
for i in range(len(li)):
    for j in range(len(li)):
        print(li[i][j])
    print()
```

And if you don't know no. of columns and in any situation, this would be helpful ==

```
for i in li:
for j in i:
    print(j,end = " ")
print()
```

You can also use the following if rows and columns are different or the same:

```
li=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9]]
for i in range(len(li)):
    for j in range(len(li[i])):
        print(li[i][j],end = " ")
   print()
```

Comment: What would be the reasoning behind using the other two loops instead of the middle one?